# mootools sortables vs jquery sortables effect

Tags: jquery, mootools, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, mootools-sortable

I've been using mootools for some time and trying jQuery for a week so this probably is a  newbie question - though I've found nothing in the manuals.

In mootools, when you use the option **clone** in a sortables list it creates a clone of your image/object that helps you visualize where the image/object will be droppped - works great on my thumbnail sorting system.

[mootools sortables doc page](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Drag/Sortables)

Well, jQuery also has that same option, **clone** but when I use it doesn't do a thing. Meaning, it in fact clones the element and the one you drag around is a clone but when you drop-it the original stays exactly where it previously was. You can check this behavior with the **draggable demo** they have on their site. Take a look at the [semi-transparent-clone](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#visual-feedback), you can move it around and when you drop it is stays right there.

Is this buggy behavior or just how its supposed to be? I could replicate mootools behavior on my own but though this would be a standard option...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I hit the panic button way to soon.

There are obvious different philosophies of though in the frameworks and, I must agree, **the cloning as it works in jQuery is more sensible**.

They could, however, have an option, maybe call it **shadow**, to double what mootools does. Nevertheless, if you are in a hurry, had my doubt and **wanna mimic mootool's behavior** just do something like this:

```
$('#galery-thumb-list').sortable({
    helper: 'clone',
    tolerance: 'pointer',

    start: function(e, ui) {
        ui.placeholder.html(ui.item.html());
        ui.placeholder.css({
            'visibility': 'visible',
            'opacity': 0.1
        });
    }
});
```

Pretty simple but confusing for a first timer as "*clone*" and "*clone*" are obviously different things in different frameworks.

Hope it helps someone!